# background-image:url not showing up image for background using css

Tags: css, html, xhtml

I am trying to set background image using background-image:url but its not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyTitle</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                 <!-- background-color:green; -->
                 background-image:url("background.jpg");
                 <!-- color:white; -->
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pls Help!!

Comment: Define "not working". Check that your image is where you want it to be, and that your path is correct. With the current path, you're assuming the image is in the same directory as the HTML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!-- comment   -->
```

is not valid comment syntax within a CSS block. That is probably breaking your CSS rule.

Try

```
/* comment */
```

Answer (score 3):

The  tag doesn't nest into the  tag.

Try

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
             /* background-color:green; */
             background-image:url("background.jpg");
             /* color:white; */
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        <title>MyTitle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And comments in CSS are defined like...

```
 /*this is a comment*/
```